# PyCharm changes keyboard layout for shortcuts under Manjaro

Tags: python, pycharm, locale, shortcut, keyboard-layout

i am using PyCharm under `Manjaro` Linux.
I have two languge bindings, `german` and `english` (which i use for coding and work). If i want to execute a short cut in PyCharm (e.g. `ctrl+z` for undo), it executes `ctrl+y`, so PyCharm switches to the german layout even though it stays in the english layout for the normal coding part. If i press `y` in the editor, a `y` is inserted.
How do i circumvent that, so that i can press `ctrl+z` and it executes undo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to enable `Use national layouts for shortcuts`
[image: enable national layouts]

Answer (score 0):

Hey for me changing the order of the keyboard layouts solved the issue. Previously it was German -> English and I swapped the order to English -> German and now it works fine. Not sure if this is works for Manjaro as well.

To change the order go to "Region & Language" in the settings and then change it with drag and drop.
[image: Swap Order of Keyboard Layouts in Ubuntu]

[Source of my solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1082915/keyboard-layout-for-shortcuts-stays-national-for-some-app-on-ubuntu-18-04-gnome)